# Android: no logcat output in Eclipse via Emulator on boot

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, logcat, boot

I'm writing an Android app that starts up on boot. I'm developing/testing it under Eclipse using the Emulator. This app is crashing during boot-up, but there is no logcat output for me to examime in order to debug this issue, even though I get proper logcat output from the same app if I invoke it manually, after boot-up, with the same Eclipse and logcat configuration.

Here's how I boot the Emulator: (1) I stop it; (2) I restart it via Android Virtual Device Manager with "launch from snapshot" NOT set. When I do this, the app starts up and dislays some Toasts before crashing, so I know it at least begins to run before dying, but I see no logcat output in Eclipse.

Does anyone know how to force logcat output to show up in Eclipse's logcat window when invoking an on-boot app within the Emulator? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It does this automatically. Make sure that you go over to the DDMS perspective and choose the new emulator instance, as LogCat may be showing you the contents of your previous emulator instance, or nothing at all if nothing is selected in the DDMS Devices view.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, CommonsWare. Thank you. Before, I didn't have the DDMS perspective open when rebooting, and all that was showing was the previous instance's logcat. Now, I see all logcat output during reboot. Problem solved. (Note: I would vote you up, but I haven't developed sufficient reputation to do so, yet).